# my jquery code dont work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

UCCN1003

Edit

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('a.edit').click(function(event){

            var change = $(this).parent('div').find('p');
            var changeText = change.text();
            var wrapper = $(this).parent('div');
            var clone = change.clone(true);

            var changeBox = $(this).parent('div').find('.editBox');
            var changeBoxText = changeBox.val();
            if($(this).text() == 'Edit'){
                wrapper.prepend("<input class='editBox' type='text' value='"+ changeText + "'/>");
                wrapper.append("<a href='#' class='save' style='margin-left:10px' >Save</a>");
                change.remove();
                $(this).text("cancel");
            }else if($(this).text()=='cancel'){
                wrapper.prepend("<p>" + changeBoxText +"</p>");
                $('.editBox').remove();
                $('.save').remove();
                $(this).text('Edit');
            }

        });


        $('.save').click(function(event){
            var editBox = $(this).parent('div').find('.editBox');
            var editBoxText = editBox.text();

            var wrapper = $(this).parent('div');
            wrapper.prepand("<p>" + editBoxText + "</p>");
            editBox.remove();
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
</script>
```

My part that work work is

```
 $('.save').click(function(event){
        var editBox = $(this).parent('div').find('.editBox');
        var editBoxText = editBox.text();

        var wrapper = $(this).parent('div');
        wrapper.prepand("<p>" + editBoxText + "</p>");
        editBox.remove();
        $(this).remove();
    });
```

where the wrapper wont prepand the p tag and the editBox and the .save wont be remove.
i try to add alert("work") in this and it wont alert at all. anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

It's this bit:  `.prepand()`, should be: [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) :)

Currently it would throw a `.prepand()` is not a function error, something along those lines, for a shorter complete version you can use [`.prependTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/) as well:

```
$('.save').live('click', function() {
  var editBox = $(this).parent('div').find('.editBox').remove();
  $("<p />", { text: editBox.val() }).prependTo($(this).parent('div'));
  $(this).remove();
});
```

At second glance I see you're adding these dynamically, in which case you should use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) like I have above, the `.click()` with a selector won't find these elements created *later*, so it'll never run :)

Comment: thank for reply, but after change to .prepend(), it still dont work :(

Comment: @kingdom - I missed another important detail, check the updated answer :)

Comment: @Nick Craver - my html markup is like this.

<div><p>UCCN1003</p><a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a></div>

Comment: work already, i didnt know about live(), thank for helping :)

Comment: @kingdom - I fixed the answer, should have been `.val()`, but I would check out something like jEditable: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable you can view a demo here: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html Even fixing the question, cancel still saves the old value, etc, so not a lot of the code you can re-use there.